# Grading Point in C

Tags: c

This is my code Everything Works fine but when i put any alphabet not numbers it shows A-.
 i just want to know why this happening.Why it Shown only A-.Can anyone explain Why this happing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num;
printf("Enter Your number ");
scanf("%d" ,& num);
    if(num>79)
    {
   printf("Congratulation you got A+");
}

else if(num>69)
{
printf("Congratulation you got A ");
}
else if(num>59)
{
printf("Congratulation you got A-");
}
else if(num>49)
    {
    printf("Congratulation you got B");
}
else if(num>39)
{
    printf("Congratulation you got C");
}

else if(num>32)
    {
    printf("Congratulation you got D");
}
else
{
    printf("You are a student like me(Shuvo) \nBetter Luck next time");

}
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior?

Comment: The `"%d` format specifier needs a numeric input. It stops scanning when it finds an alphabet character, which remains in the input buffer. You did not initialise `int num;` so anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Inititalize variable num to before using it. I mean replace the line "int num;" by "int num = 0;". Here is my solution

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num = 0;
    printf("Enter Your number ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 79)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got A+");
    }

    else if (num > 69)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got A ");
    }
    else if (num > 59)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got A-");
    }
    else if (num > 49)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got B");
    }
    else if (num > 39)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got C");
    }

    else if (num > 32)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got D");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You are a student like me(Shuvo) \nBetter Luck next time");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf will discard any input in the input stream if the data don't match the format specifier.

The scanf specifier in your code is %d, discards any characters other than integers. To check how many characters are read by scanf(), better print scanf() return data.

int count = scanf(...);

Comment: Only leading whitespace is **discarded**, any other non-numeric input remains in the buffer. The return value from `scanf` function family is the number of *items* successfully processed.

Answer (score 0):

Well the expected input is any integer and output is grade note information. If your input is unexpected like a character, then you will get something unexpected right?

```
scanf("%d" ,& num);
```

The placeholder %d in scanf requires an integer input so it's not going to read any integer values if you supply it with a character.

**to fix this you can add an error check statement:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> /*for exit*/
int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Enter Your number ");

    if(scanf("%d" ,& num) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Bad input!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(num>79)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got A+");
    }
    else if(num>69)
    {    
        printf("Congratulation you got A ");
    }
    else if(num>59)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got A-");
    }
    else if(num>49)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got B");
    }
    else if(num>39)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got C");
    }
    else if(num>32)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you got D");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You are a student like me(Shuvo) \nBetter Luck next time");
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Is it fine now? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
      char str[100], ch;
      int i, grade[5];
      float credit[5], gpa = 0.0, totCredit = 0.0;

      /* get the letter grade and credits from the user */
      printf("Letter Grade and Credits for each subject:\n");
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              printf("Subject %d(Grade|Credit):", i + 1);
              ch = getchar();
              grade[i] = ch;
              scanf("%f", &credit[i]);
              getchar();
      }

      /* print the input grades and credits */
      printf("\nSubject | Grade | Credit\n");
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              printf("   %d    |  %c    | %.0f\n", i + 1, grade[i], credit[i]);
      }

      /* calculate gpa value */
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              switch (grade[i]) {
                      case 'S':
                              gpa = gpa + 10 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;
                      case 'A':
                              gpa = gpa + 9 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;

                      case 'B':
                              gpa = gpa + 8 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;

                      case 'C':
                              gpa = gpa + 7 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;

                      case 'D':
                              gpa = gpa + 6 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;

                      case 'E':
                              gpa = gpa + 5 * credit[i];
                              totCredit = totCredit + credit[i];
                              break;

                      default:
                              printf("Given Wrong grade!!\n");
                              exit(0);

              }
      }
      printf("GPA: %f\tcredit: %f\n", gpa, totCredit);
      gpa = gpa / totCredit;
      printf("GPA for your score: %.2f\n", gpa);
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  int num;
  printf("Enter your mark ");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  printf(" You entered %d", num); // printing outputs

  if(num >= 80){
    printf(" You got A grade"); // printing outputs
  }
  else if ( num >=60){ // Note the space between else & if
    printf(" You got B grade");
  }
  else if ( num >=40){
    printf(" You got C grade");
  }

  else if ( num < 40){
    printf(" You Failed in this exam");
  }
  return 0;
}
```