# Can I associate a character to a desired integer of my choosing?

Tags: c

Without using maps.

For example,

I initialize a variable called grade_letter.

I ask a user to input a letter grade (A,B,C,D,F).

How can I assign A to 90%, B to 80%, C to 70%, ...?

A -> 90, B-> 80, C ->70

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char grade_letter;
    printf("Enter a letter grade: ");
    scanf("%c", &grade_letter);
    ...
    
}
```

Comment: Use `switch/case`

Comment: This is the reverse of the standard "marks to grades" problem - "grades to marks". So just use a `switch` statement or an `if` statement ([examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496773/grading-point-in-c)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use if/else or switch/case condition. Below is an example of this problem using if/else condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char grade_letter;
    printf("Enter a letter grade: ");
    scanf(" %c", &grade_letter);
    if(grade_letter=='A')
    {
        printf("\nyou got 90% marks");
    }

    else if(grade_letter=='B')
    {
        printf("\nyou got 80% marks ");
    }
    ...
    return 0 ;
}
```